# Smooth line between set of points

Tags: python, matplotlib, fibonacci

I want the lines uniting the values to be smooth round lines. I tried wit interp1d but I do not seem to wrap my head around the 1-d array requirement.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

a = int(input("what number?\n"))

X_Values, Y_Values, fibonacci = [0] * a, [0] * a, [0] * a
X_Values[0], Y_Values [0] = 0, 0
X_Values[1], Y_Values[1] = 1, 1
fibonacci[0] = 1
fibonacci[1] = 1
counter = 2

for i in range(2,a):
   fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i-1] + fibonacci[i-2]
   if counter == 0:
       X_Values[i] = 0
       Y_Values[i] = -fibonacci[i]
       counter += 1
   elif counter == 1:
       X_Values[i] = fibonacci[i]
       Y_Values[i] = 0
       counter += 1
   elif counter == 2:
       X_Values[i] = 0
       Y_Values[i] = fibonacci[i]
       counter += 1
   elif counter == 3:
       X_Values[i] = -fibonacci[i]
       Y_Values[i] = 0
       counter = 0


plt.axhline(y=0, color='k') 
plt.axvline(x=0, color='k')
plt.plot(X_Values, Y_Values, '*-g')
plt.title("Flow Chart of a Fibonacci series with %i elements" %a)
plt.figtext(0.5, 0.025, "The {0}th number of the Fibonacci serie is: {1}".format(a, fibonacci[-1]), ha="center", fontsize=8, bbox={"facecolor":"orange", "alpha":0.5, "pad":5})
print("The ", a, "th Fibonacci number is: ", fibonacci[a-1])
plt.show()
```

And is there a way to shorten the if elif loop to assign the coordinates to X and Y _values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a smooth interpolation, you probably can use [Bézier splines](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/quad_bezier.html). You could calculate an in-between point by adding `X[i]` and `X[i+1]`, and `Y[i]` and `Y[i+1]`.

Things would look nicer using circular arcs.  Starting angles will be `-90, 0, 90, 180, 270, ...`. End angles will be the start angle plus 90. The width and height are a bit tricky, as their role is constantly switched.  It will either be Fibonacci number i and i+1, or the other way around. `i % 2` and `(i+1) % 2` will take care of the switching.

To make the calculation with less code, first note that `counter` isn't needed, as it is just `i mod 4`.  The rotating directions can be stored in two list, `dir_x` and `dir_y`.  Also, the first two values can be set via an if-test (`if i < 2`), so they can use the same assignments for the x and y position.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc

a = int(input("what number?\n"))

X_Values, Y_Values, fibonacci = [0] * a, [0] * a, [0] * a

dir_x = [0, 1, 0, -1]
dir_y = [-1, 0, 1, 0]
for i in range(0, a):
    if i < 2:
        fibonacci[i] = 1
    else:
        fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i - 1] + fibonacci[i - 2]
    X_Values[i] = dir_x[i % 4] * fibonacci[i]
    Y_Values[i] = dir_y[i % 4] * fibonacci[i]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(a - 1):
    ax.add_patch(Arc((0, 0), width=fibonacci[i + (i + 1) % 2] * 2, height=fibonacci[i + i % 2] * 2,
                     theta1=(i - 1) * 90, theta2=i * 90, color='crimson', lw=2))
# ax.relim() # needed to calculate the x and y limits if no lines are added to the plot
# ax.autoscale()
ax.axis('equal') # equal distances on x and on y
ax.axis('off') # hide the surrounding axes

ax.axhline(y=0, color='k')
ax.axvline(x=0, color='k')
ax.plot(X_Values, Y_Values, '*--g', lw=0.5)
ax.set_title("Flow Chart of a Fibonacci series with %i elements" % a)
ax.text(0.5, -0.05, f"The {a}th number of the Fibonacci serie is: {fibonacci[-1]}", ha="center",
        fontsize=8, bbox={"facecolor": "orange", "alpha": 0.5, "pad": 5}, transform=ax.transAxes)
print("The ", a, "th Fibonacci number is: ", fibonacci[a - 1])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: The code to create the arcs can be further simplified using its `angle` parameter. `angle` is an extra rotation given to the arc, which removes the need for alternating width and height.

```py
ax.add_patch(Arc((0, 0), width=fibonacci[i] * 2, height=fibonacci[i + 1] * 2,
                 angle=(i - 1) * 90, theta1=0, theta2=90, color='crimson', lw=2))
```

The code to draw quadratic Bézier curves:

```py
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch, Path

x, y = X_Values, Y_Values
for i in range(a - 1):
    ax.add_patch(PathPatch(
        Path([(x[i], y[i]), (x[i] + x[i + 1], y[i] + y[i + 1]), (x[i + 1], y[i + 1])],
             [Path.MOVETO, Path.CURVE3, Path.CURVE3]),
        fc="none", ec='navy', transform=ax.transData))
```